# File sharing problem with OneDrive

Tags: office-365, onedrive-for-business, onedrive

File sharing problem with OneDrive

Message error

{"code":"-2130575136, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException","message":{"lang":"fr-FR","value":"Couldn't resolve user i:0#.f|membership|ahemard-ligne14_hotmail.com#ext#@bouyguesconstruction.onmicrosoft.com."},"status":500,"retryAfter":0,"authenticate":null,"correlationId":"9efdcb9f-e01e-2000-ea85-968c9c04b441"}

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As it can be seen, from the format of the email that the user has, he is an external user.
Have you checked that the user's identity still exists within the Azure Active Directory?
Has the user accepted the invitation?

Since the user is external, there's not much that can be done, other than the basic check that the users exists within the directory and he has accepted the invitation.

Please note that the user must be licensed in order to be complaint with MS.

Comment: Hello,
Yes I checked in the directory he exist, I made a test I shared a file with him and it worked without any problem (in onedrive online and in desktop).

the problem he has is only with a single user that he cannot share files with him, neither in onedrive online nor in the windows file explorer

Answer (score 1):

Experienced this error and it turned out the account we were sharing with was disabled ('sign in blocked') in Azure Active Directory.

[image: Something went wrong code -2130575136]

> Something went wrong
>
> Sorry, we're unable to reach the server right now. Please try again later.
>
> {"code":"-2130575136, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Couldn't resolve user i:0#.f|membership|username@example.com."},"status":500,"retryAfter":0,"authenticate":null,"correlationId":"5c5cfb9f-6071-c000-5e56-493f4e48a2c5"}

Try enabling the account you are sharing to in Azure Active Directory, and the error may go away.